# Using the Firebase Admin SDK for Java, how can I authenticate a user with email and password?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm trying to figure out how to authenticate a user using the Java Firebase SDK using the email and password. But going through the documentation, I can't seem to find a way on how to do it.

This is the documentation I've been looking at -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

Would anyone be able to help out?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  What information do you have available about the user?  Are you trying to validate an email/password pair?

Comment: 1. What exactly are you trying to do? - I'm trying to use Firebase with Spark on Java. 

2. What information do you have available about the user?  - I have the email and password collected from user. My hope is to get the user record using email and authenticate. 
3. Are you trying to validate an email/password pair? - Yes. Initial thought was to validate an email/password similar to something like this on Android https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth

Comment: The Admin SDK doesn't offer this sort of functionality.  It needs to be done on a web or mobile client using its native SDK.